# Get Selected Item from dropdown and pass it to an onClick event

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get **Selected Item** from drop down list populated by SQL db and pass it to an onclick event of a button

```
<th>Select Club</th>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("Clubs", new SelectList(Model.Clubs.Select(x => x.Name)), "Select Club")</td>

<input type="button" onclick="AssignPlayertoClub(@Model.Player.ID,"Clubs.SelectedValue")"/> //<-- Selected Value here
```

So signature of **AssignPlayertoClub(ID,Club)** is this. I read a lot of answers on this issue but nothing fixes mine as most of them use Viewbag

This is my method in **Controller** Method to be called onClick

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AssignPlayertoClub(int ID,Club club)
    {
        await playerRepo.AssignPlayer(ID, club);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I'm using JQuery Ajax to call the controller method like this

```
function AssignPlayertoClub(Id, club) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Player/AssignPlayertoClub',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { Id: Id, club: club },
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = data;
    }
}).done(() => alert("Player Assigned"));
}
```

If any other code is required. Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your `Club` looks like. Suppose we define the `Club` as below :

```cs
public class Club
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Firstly, I would suggest you using a `Club.Id` to identity the `option`:

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("Clubs", new SelectList(Model.Clubs,"Id","Name"), "Select Club")
</td>
```

Now we need to get the current selected value when clicking the submit button. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Get_information_about_the_selected_option), we could get the current club's Id in the following way:

```
<input type="button" onclick="var selected=Clubs.options[Clubs.selectedIndex].value;AssignPlayertoClub(@Model.Player.ID,selected)"/> //<-- Selected Value here
```

Lastly, your server is expecting an instance of `Club` from client side. That's not safe. It's possible that an user fakes a club name and then harm your system. A safe way is to receive an `Club.Id` instead of the whole `Club` instance. To fix that, make the method accept a parameter of `Club.Id`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AssignPlayertoClub(int ID,Id club)
{ 
    var club = await clubRepo.FindAsync(Id);
    await playerRepo.AssignPlayer(ID, club);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

**[Another approach]**: send an instance of club instead of club's Id (**NOT SAFE**)

```
    function getClubs(){
        var x = document.querySelectorAll("#Clubs option");
        var clubs = [];
        x.forEach(i => {
            var value = i.getAttribute("value");
            var text = i.textContent;
            if(value !="") { clubs.push({id: value, name: text}); }
        });
        return clubs;
    }
    function AssignPlayertoClub(Id, clubId) {
        var clubs = getClubs();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Player/AssignPlayertoClub',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Id: Id, club :clubs[clubId]},
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = data;
            }
        }).done(() => alert("Player Assigned"));
    }
```

The server side action method is the same as yours :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AssignPlayertoClub(int ID,Club club)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: As it helped me a lot but it still always send me value=0 when i click button (following safe approach). I can see value of every item when i see my code in chrome dev tools. But when my ajax hits my controller method its clubId=0

Comment: Actually i solved it using jquery as when i change the selected item it updates the selected variable. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ShivamSood For the first comment: Sorry there's a typo in my code. I've updated my code:  rename the `Id clubId` to `Id club`. It happens because the ajax function `function AssignPlayertoClub(Id, clubId) {/*...*/}`  is sending something like`id=1&club=c` , but the server expects sth like `Id=1&clubId=c`.